# How to Draw a polygon

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm making a program that will draw a Serpenksiy's Triangle on a Decart and Polar coordinate system. I thought that using `Polygon()` will be perfect for that, but for some reason it does not draw a triangle, it draws a line. I do not understand why, and I can't come up with an answer.

Here is the code:

```pascal
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls;
type
  TGraphForm = class(TForm)
    img1: TImage;
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  GraphForm: TGraphForm;

implementation

uses
  Unit1;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TGraphForm.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Ax, Ay, Bx, By, Cx, Cy: integer;
  x0, y0 :integer;
begin
  //взятие параметров  Defining Points of Triangle
  Ax := StrToInt(MainForm.EditAx.Text);
  Ay := StrToInt(MainForm.EditAy.Text);

  Bx := StrToInt(MainForm.EditBx.Text);
  By := StrToInt(MainForm.EditBx.Text);

  Cx := StrToInt(MainForm.EditCx.Text);
  Cy := StrToInt(MainForm.EditCx.Text);

  //0 функции      Center of system (0;0)
  x0 := img1.Width div 2;
  y0 := img1.Height div 2;

  //Оси           Drawing Axis
  with img1.Canvas do
  begin
    MoveTo(x0,0);
    LineTo(x0, ClientHeight);
    MoveTo(0, y0);
    LineTo(ClientWidth, y0);
  end;

  //график

  //главный треугольник
  with img1.Canvas do
  begin
    Polygon ([Point(-Ax+x0,-Ay+y0), Point(-Bx+x0,-By+y0), Point(-Cx+x0,-Cy+y0)]);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Not related to your triangle, but in your calls to `img1.Canvas.LineTo()` when drawing a cross over the `TImage`, you are using the Form's `Client(Width|Height)` properties where you should be using the `Timage`'s `Width|Height` properties instead.

Comment: Regarding your triangle, what are the actual input values you are using? And what are the dimensions of the `TForm` and `TImage`? For all we know, you are drawing outside of the `TImage`'s client area, which could explain why you don't see it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau im using Ax=7, Ay=1, Bx=4, By=4, Cx=6, Cy=7. Regarding the dimension question, i don't really get it. Am i drawing outside of Timage area? How's that?

Comment: "*Am i drawing outside of Timage area? How's that?*" - I can't answer that yet, since you have not provided the `TImage`'s actual `Width|Height`... Oh wait, one issue I just saw is when you are assigning `By` and `Cy` from the `MainForm` input, you are reading the values from the wrong UI controls - you are reading `By` from `EditBx` instead of `EditBy`, and reading `Cy` from `EditCx` instead of `EditCy`

Comment: @RemyLebeau i marked in properties of TImage AutoSize on true, so when user decide to change the size of the window(form) it would scale with the window(form), but if it stays in one position without changing size of the form then Hight is 516 and Width is 864 . I fixed the issue with Edits but problem still remains :c

Comment: in that case, I don't recommend using a TImage, I would suggest a TPaintBox instead. But in any case, you are using very small coordinates on a very large image, so it makes sense that you would not see very much being drawn. Also, why are you using multiplication on the middle `Point` but not the other `Point`s?

Comment: The multiplication was a missclick. Using `TPointBox` there is no such event as `OnActivate`, how would you make it draw when it's been open? And will the method through `Polygon()` even work?

Comment: use the `TPaintBox.OnPaint` event. Or, you could get rid of the `TPaintBox` and just draw directly on the `TForm` in its own `OnPaint` event.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, i made it and added a multiplayer variable that make coordinates "bigger", but how to make it do something like `AutoResize` does in properties? There is no such thing for `TPaintBox`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the comments on the OP's answer, it is clear that the OP doesn't fully understand the concepts involved. To help the OP, I'd like to answer him/her in the comments thread, but due to technical limitations (comment length, formatting, etc.), I am unable to.

Therefore I write this "pseudoanswer" for the benefit of the OP. When the OP has read this answer, I may delete it.

---

Create a new VCL application. Then add the following `OnPaint` handler:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin

  // Clear background
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);

  // Draw a circle
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clNavy;
  var P := ClientRect.CenterPoint;
  Canvas.Ellipse(P.X - 20, P.Y - 20, P.X + 20, P.Y + 20);

end;
```

The `OnPaint` handler is called every time the form needs to redraw itself.

Please note that I first clear the background; otherwise we'll end up with more and more circles as the form is repainted.

Now, we also want to redraw the form every time it is resized. To this end, add a `OnResize` handler:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Invalidate;
end;
```

[image: Screen recording]

To further illustrate the principle, let's animate the ball so it bounces in a simulated field of gravity. To this end, add private instance variables to the form:

```pascal
private
  x,  y,            // position
  vx, vy,           // velocity
  ax, ay: Double;   // acceleration
```

and in the `OnCreate` handler, give them initial values:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  x := ClientWidth / 2;
  y := ClientHeight / 2;
  vx := 1000;
  vy := 1000;
  ax := 0;
  ay := 6000;
end;
```

Then add a `TTimer` to the form, set its `Interval` to `30` and give it the following `OnTimer` event handler:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin

  const dt = 0.01;

  vx := vx + ax * dt;
  vy := vy + ay * dt;

  x := x + vx * dt;
  y := y + vy * dt;

  if x < 0 then
  begin
    vx := -0.9*vx;
    x := 1;
  end;

  if x > ClientWidth then
  begin
    vx := -0.9*vx;
    x := ClientWidth - 1;
  end;

  if y < 0 then
  begin
    vy := -0.9*vy;
    y := 1;
  end;

  if y > ClientHeight then
  begin
    vy := -0.9*vy;
    y := ClientHeight - 1;
  end;

  Invalidate;

end;
```

and change the `OnPaint` handler to

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin

  // Clear background
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);

  // Draw a circle
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clNavy;
  var CentrePoint := Point(Round(x), Round(y));
  const R = 10;
  Canvas.Ellipse(CentrePoint.X - R, CentrePoint.Y - R, CentrePoint.X + R, CentrePoint.Y + R);

end;
```

You may notice some flickering. To get rid of this, the standard trick is to add a

```
procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
```

message handler to your form class:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd);
begin
  Message.Result := 1;
end;
```

For extra fun, add the following `OnClick` handler:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  vx := 5000 * (Random + 0.5);
  vy := 5000 * (Random + 0.5);
end;
```

[image: Screen recording]

Answer (score 0):

So, with help from Remy Lebeau (the great man) i fixed the problem. Actually, i have no clue how, but now it works. Here is the changed code:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, System.Types;
type
  TGraphForm = class(TForm)
    img: TImage;
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  GraphForm: TGraphForm;

implementation
 uses
  Unit1;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TGraphForm.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
  var
  // переменные Variables
  Ax, Ay, Bx, By, Cx, Cy: integer;
  x0, y0 :integer;
  scale :integer;
begin
     // координаты вершин  Points of triangle
  Ax := StrToInt(MainForm.EditAx.Text)*-1;
  Ay := StrToInt(MainForm.EditAy.Text)*-1;
  Bx := StrToInt(MainForm.EditBx.Text)*-1;
  By := StrToInt(MainForm.EditBy.Text)*-1;
  Cx := StrToInt(MainForm.EditCx.Text)*-1;
  Cy := StrToInt(MainForm.EditCy.Text)*-1;
   // точка пересечения осей Where is the zero
  x0 := img.Width div 2;
  y0 := img.Height div 2;
  // множитель масштабирования scale multiplier
  scale :=-40;

  with img.Canvas do
    begin
    //рисование осей    drawing Axises
      MoveTo(x0, 0);
      LineTo(x0, img.Height);
      MoveTo(0, y0);
      LineTo(img.Width, y0);
      //Making poligon (triangle)
      Brush.Color := clBlack;
      Polygon( [Point(Ax*scale+x0, Ay*-scale+y0), Point(Bx*scale+x0, By*-scale+y0), Point(Cx*scale+x0, Cy*-scale+y0)] );
    end;
end;
end.
```

Comment: You are not supposed to draw in any other methods than ``OnPaint``

Comment: @DelphiCoder what does that mean?

Comment: @rawhu: It is wrong to put your drawing code in the `OnActivate` handler. That will lead to a lot of problems for you. You must put all your drawing code in the `OnPaint` handler instead.

Comment: when i put my code on `OnPaint` event the image of graph don't want to scale with resizing the form :c

Comment: @rawhu: Add an OnResize handler to your form with this code, a single line: `Invalidate`. Also: If you paint in a form event handler, you should paint on the form's canvas. If you need to paint in a child control, use a `TPaintBox`.

Comment: sorry for poor english, i mean that triangle and marks on axises and other stuff don't want to scale together with the form. Triangle do not stretch or shrink no matter how big or small the form is

Comment: If you are using the form's canvas, don't write `img.Height`, `img.Width`, etc. Use `Self.Height`, `Self.Width`, etc. , which is the same thing as `Height`, `Width` etc. since `Self` is implicit. Indeed, `img.Height` is the height of the image; `Self.Height` is the height of the object on which the method belongs, that is, your form if you are using the form's `OnPaint` handler. BUT: You really want `ClientHeight` and `ClientWidth` instead so you don't count the form's borders. So replace `img.Height` with `ClientHeight` and `img.Width` with `ClientWidth`.

Comment: i changed img.Height to what you said, but it still do not shrink or strech and also it looks like every time i move the window, graph draws itself on his previous version, so the absolute hell occures.

Comment: @rawhu: Every time you repaint the form, you need to start by clearing it. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72912274/282848).